# Spring joint working like rope not like a spring

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use spring joint 2d in my game. Here I have little code with spring joint I am trying to create a game like angry bird. But here I can't get spring joint 2d working. Its work like a rope, not getting streatch like spring.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems; 

public class Projectile_dragging : MonoBehaviour {

    public LineRenderer catapultLineFront;
    public LineRenderer catapultLineBack;


    private bool clickedOn;

    void Start(){
        LineRenderersetup ();
    }
    void Update(){

        if(clickedOn)
            Dragging();

        LineRendererUpdate ();
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){

        clickedOn = true;
    }
    void OnMouseUp(){
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
        clickedOn = false;
    }


    void LineRendererUpdate(){
        //Vector2 hold = transform.position - catapultLineFront.transform.position;
        Vector3 hold = transform.position;
        //leftRay.direction = projectile;
        //Vector3 hold = leftRay.GetPoint(projectile.magnitude + radius);
        catapultLineFront.SetPosition(1, hold);
        catapultLineBack.SetPosition(1, hold);
    }

    void LineRenderersetup(){
        catapultLineBack.SetPosition (0, catapultLineBack.transform.position);
        catapultLineFront.SetPosition (0, catapultLineFront.transform.position);

        catapultLineBack.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
        catapultLineFront.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";

        catapultLineBack.sortingOrder = 1;
        catapultLineFront.sortingOrder = 3;

    }

    void Dragging(){
        Vector3 mouseworldpoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        mouseworldpoint.z = 0f;
        transform.position = mouseworldpoint;


    }


}
```

[image: Image of spring joint 2d attached object.]

Comment: I see only `LineRenderer`'s, but where did you create the `Spring Joint 2D` ?

Comment: ohh I attacheed it manually.

Comment: Could you include a picture of your `GameObject` with the attached `SpringJoint`, and possibly a video describing your problem? You need to specify where you placed the spring and what should it propel.

Comment: @Hristo I attached image here pls check that.